# Generate Random Tree with Different number of children

Tags: r, igraph

In igraph there seems to be methods to generate trees where the branches have the same number of children, for example a binary graph.

```
make_tree(10,children=2)
```

I want to know is there a way to generate a real random tree where the number of children always differ. I do not want to concatenate a graph with another graph nor specify the tree in a literal fashion.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What stochastic process do you want for the depth and breadth of the tree? For example, do you want to start with one node and then have Poisson(3) children? Or Uniform(0,4)?

Comment: @Spacedman I probably would want a distribution that spans a large support of number of children. Something like a poisson will do.

Comment: And the depth? How do you stop the graph becoming huge?

Comment: @Spacedman Perhaps also governed by some Poisson distribution. Or even a pareto fat-tailed.. I undecided but I want the tree to reflect the shape or distributions as though it was a sample from the body of open-source dependency graphs but i am uncertain of the distribution.